# dplyr if_else() vs base R ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am fairly proficient within the Tidyverse, but have always used `ifelse()` instead of dplyr `if_else()`. I want to switch this behavior and default to always using `dplyr::if_else()` and deprecating `ifelse()` from my code.

Is there any reason not to do this? Would this likely get me into trouble? I'll spare you the details, but recently, not using `if_else()` screwed me up, when I unknowingly created a column of character matrices in my data analysis. If I switch to always using `if_else()` I hope to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Related: [if_else() `false` must be type double, not integer - in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708366/if-else-false-must-be-type-double-not-integer-in-r/50708505#50708505)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`if_else` is more strict. It checks that both alternatives are of the same type and otherwise throws an error, while `ifelse` will promote types as necessary. This may be a benefit in some circumstances, but may otherwise break scripts if you don't check for errors or explicitly force type conversion. For example:

```
ifelse(c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),"a",3)
[1] "a" "a" "3"
if_else(c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),"a",3)
Error: `false` must be type character, not double
```

Answer (score 24):

Another reason to choose `if_else` over `ifelse` is that `ifelse` turns `Date` into `numeric` objects

```r
Dates <- as.Date(c('2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', '2018-10-03'))
new_Dates <- ifelse(Dates == '2018-10-02', Dates + 1, Dates)
str(new_Dates)

#>  num [1:3] 17805 17807 17807
```

[`if_else` is also faster than `ifelse`](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/performance.html).

Note that when testing multiple conditions, the code would be more readable and less error-prone if we use `case_when`.

```r
library(dplyr)

case_when(
  Dates == '2018-10-01' ~ Dates - 1,
  Dates == '2018-10-02' ~ Dates + 1,
  Dates == '2018-10-03' ~ Dates + 2,
  TRUE ~ Dates
)

#> [1] "2018-09-30" "2018-10-03" "2018-10-05"
```

Created on 2018-06-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: what's the difference between `if_else` and `case_when` for one condition?

Comment: [`if_else`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/if_else.R) & [`case_when`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/case_when.R)

Comment: Does not answer my question.

Answer (score 13):

I'd also add that `if_else()` can attribute a value in case of `NA`, which is a handy way of adding an extra condition.

```
df <- data_frame(val = c(80, 90, NA, 110))
df %>% mutate(category = if_else(val < 100, 1, 2, missing = 9))

#     val category
#   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1    80        1
# 2    90        1
# 3    NA        9
# 4   110        2
```

Comment: How could you accomplish this with base R `ifelse()` to add the `missing = 9`? And your code is a little off. It should be `if_else(value < 100, 1, 2, missing = 9)`.

Comment: To answer @stackinator:  the base equivalent is `ifelse(is.na(val), 9, ifelse(val < 100, 1, 2))`.

Comment: I started to use `if_else` after this project, clean, tidy and concise...
https://github.com/englianhu/binary.com-interview-question/blob/master/binary-Q1Multi-GARCH.Rmd

Answer (score 5):

Another important reason for preferring `if_else()` to `ifelse()` is checking for consistency in lengths. See this dangerous gotcha:

```
> tibble(x = 1:3, y = ifelse(TRUE, x, 4:6))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     3     1
```

Compare with

```
> tibble(x = 1:3, y = if_else(TRUE, x, 4:6))
    Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 3.
```

The intention in both cases is clearly for column `y` to equal `x` or to equal `4:6` acording to the value of a single (scalar) logical variable; `ifelse()` silently truncates its output to length 1, which is then silently recycled. `if_else()` catches what is almost certainly an error at source.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I prefer `ifelse` because it does not evaluate the false statement. When you raise error if the condition is not TRUE, you have to use a simple `if`, or `ifelse`.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2))
df %>% mutate(shp = ifelse(
    length(a) >= 3,
    round(shapiro.test(a)[["p.value"]], 3L),
    NA_real_
))
  a shp
1 1  NA
2 2  NA
df %>% mutate(shp = if_else(
    length(a) >= 3,
    round(shapiro.test(a)[["p.value"]], 3L),
    NA_real_
))
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `shp = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `shapiro.test()`:
! sample size must be between 3 and 5000
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```