# if_else() `false` must be type double, not integer - in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

The end of a long string of dplyr pipes is

`mutate(n = if_else(FiscalYear == "FY2018" & Candy == "SNICKERS", n - 3, n))`

which gives this error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: `false` must be type double, not integer.
```

Which goes away if I do either of these two instead

`mutate(n = ifelse(FiscalYear == "FY2018" & Candy == "SNICKERS", n - 3, n))`

`mutate(n = if_else(FiscalYear == "FY2018" & Candy == "SNICKERS", n - 3L, n))`

I thought it'd be easiest to make a simple reproducible recreation so I did what you see below, but I can't get the error anymore. Any idea what's going on? **Why does `ifelse` work where `if_else` doesn't, and why does `if_else` work if I change 3 to 3L?** I understand `L` *coerces* 3 to be an integer, is that correct?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~fruit, ~qty,
  "Bob", "apple", 10,
  "Bill", "apple", 10
)

# THIS WORKS AGAIN AS IT SHOULD
df %>% mutate(qty = ifelse(name == "Bob" & fruit == "apple", qty / 2, qty))

# BUT IF_ELSE DOESN'T FAIL THIS TIME, WEIRD
df %>% mutate(qty = if_else(name == "Bob" & fruit == "apple", qty / 2, qty))
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`if_else` from `dplyr` is type-stable, meaning that it checks whether the "true" and "false" conditions are the same type. If they aren't, `if_else` throws an error. `ifelse` in Base R does not do that.

When writing:

```
mutate(n = if_else(FiscalYear == "FY2018" & Candy == "SNICKERS", n - 3, n))
```

I assume `n` was originally an integer type, so "false" would be of integer type, `n-3` coerces "true" to a double, because `3` is double. "true" and "false" are of different types, so `if_else` throws an error.

When writing:

```
mutate(qty = if_else(name == "Bob" & fruit == "apple", qty / 2, qty))
```

`qty` is likely already a double, so dividing a double by `2` (a double) still yields a double. "true" and "false" are the same type. Hence no error.

With that being said, this can easily be checked with the following `typeof`s:

```
> typeof(6)
[1] "double"

> typeof(6L)
[1] "integer"

> typeof(6L-3)
[1] "double"

> typeof(6L-3L)
[1] "integer"

> typeof(6/2)
[1] "double"
```

`ifelse` from Base R does implicit coercing, which converts everything to the same type. This means that it doesn't throw an error when "true" and "false" are of different types. This is both more convenient and dangerous as there might be unexpected results after implicit coercing.

I recommend using `ifelse` for one-off/adhoc programs, and `if_else` for when you want to take advantage of the built-in unit test.

Comment: It's right in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.5/topics/if_else

Comment: @bk18 Exactly, but I thought I'd make it even more explicit for those who are still confused.