# R - if_else assign na value

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe in R. My goal is to create a new column with `if_else` statement. If the value in a row is equal to the string `"company"`, then the value of this new column will be the value from data column. Otherwise, I'd like to assign to if `NA` value.

I don't know how to achieve that, my code below does not work. Because of a different data type.

```
library(dplyr)
  active_labels <- data %>%
      mutate(start_date = if_else(type == "company", date, NA) 


Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type double, not logica
```

Comment: Try: `active_labels <- data %>%
      mutate(start_date = if_else(type == "company", date, NA_real_) `

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708366/if-else-false-must-be-type-double-not-integer-in-r/50708505

Comment: Just want to add a quick comment to say `NA_real_` doesn't work anymore; use `NA_Date_` from `lubridate` instead.

Answer (score 30):

From the help page of `if_else`:

> Compared to the base ‘ifelse()’, this function is more strict. It
>        checks that ‘true’ and ‘false’ are the same type.

That means that `date` and `NA` must be of the same type. As it happens, `NA` has also a type and it is `logical`:

```
typeof(NA)
# [1] "logical"
```

Thus, you need a typed version of `NA`. Depending on which type `date`  is you should use either:

- `NA_real_     : typeof(NA_real_)      # [1] "double"`
- `NA_integer_  : typeof(NA_integer_)   # [1] "integer"`
- `NA_character_: typeof(NA_character_) # [1] "character"`
- `NA_complex_  : typeof(NA_complex_)   # [1] "complex"`

If `date` is none of the above, you should fall back to `ifelse`.

---

Edit: from the error message you got, you should most probably use `NA_real_`

Comment: Thank you for this @thothal. I have been struggling with NA in several arguments....had no idea you could assign a type to it.

Comment: Thank you. It also made me realize I can use `base::ifelse()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Might be able to use `dplyr::case_when` here as well

```
library(dplyr)
  active_labels <- data %>%
      mutate(start_date = case_when(type == "company" ~ date, 
                                    TRUE ~ NA)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `na_if()`, this works with Dates.

```
library(dplyr)
active_labels <- data %>%
  mutate(start_date = date,
         start_date = na_if(type, "company"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
active_labels <- data
active_labels$start_date <- ifelse (active_labels$type == "company", active_labels$date, NA)
```

Hope it helps.