# How to change the value in a row if condition met in the previous row under dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there any alternative way to replace the following codes under dplyr to avoid explicit loop and data name to achieve the following?

This is to create an adjusted date, if the condition of the current supp_date less than the previous supp_date + tablet is met.

Sample data: (This is the new sample data with `else` case in it.)

```
test <- read.table(text =
    "supp_date    tablet
2017-07-19    30
2017-08-07    30
2017-09-08    30
2017-10-30    30
2017-11-08    30
2017-12-07    30", header = T)
```

R code:

```
test$supp_date <- as.Date(test$supp_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
test$adj_fill_dt <- as.Date(NA, "%Y-%m-%d")
test$adj_fill_dt[1] <- test$supp_date[1]
for(i in 2:6) {
  if (test[i, "supp_date"] < test[i-1, "adj_fill_dt"] + test[i-1, "tablet"]) {
      test[i, "adj_fill_dt"] <- test[i-1, "adj_fill_dt"] + test[i-1, "tablet"]
  } else {
    test[i, "adj_fill_dt"] <- test[i, "supp_date"]
  }
}
```

From:

```
supp_date    tablet
2017-07-19    30
2017-08-07    30
2017-09-08    30
2017-10-30    30
2017-11-08    30
2017-12-07    30
```

To:

```
supp_date    tablet   adj_fill_dt
2017-07-19    30       2017-07-19
2017-08-07    30       2017-08-18
2017-09-08    30       2017-09-17
2017-10-30    30       2017-10-30
2017-11-08    30       2017-11-29
2017-12-07    30       2017-12-29
```

Comment: What's in column `"target_dose"`? Do you mean `tablet`? I assume the unit of `tablet` is days?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Sorry about that. Did some editing on the code, forgot to change it. And yes, you can assume that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reproduces your expected output

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    mutate(
        supp_date = as.Date(supp_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
        adj_fill_dt = if_else(
            supp_date < supp_date[1] + cumsum(tablet),
            lag(supp_date[1] + cumsum(tablet), default = supp_date[1]),
            supp_date))
#   supp_date tablet adj_fill_dt
#1 2017-07-19     30  2017-07-19
#2 2017-08-07     30  2017-08-18
#3 2017-09-08     30  2017-09-17
#4 2017-10-11     30  2017-10-17
#5 2017-11-08     30  2017-11-16
#6 2017-12-07     30  2017-12-16
```

Please note that this requires some thorough testing with larger sample data; with the sample data you give, we never make it into the `else` part of the `if_else` (or in your case `if {...} else {...}`) condition.

The key here is to realise that the recursive relation in your `if` condition can be rewritten as `supp_date[1] + cumsum(tablet)`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "supp_date    tablet
2017-07-19    30
2017-08-07    30
2017-09-08    30
2017-10-11    30
2017-11-08    30
2017-12-07    30", header = T)
```

---

### Update

The following reproduces the output for both of your examples

```
df %>%
    mutate(
        supp_date = as.Date(supp_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
        grp = cumsum(!(supp_date < lag(supp_date[1] + cumsum(tablet), default = supp_date[1])))) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(adj_fill_dt = lag(supp_date[1] + cumsum(tablet), default = supp_date[1]))
## A tibble: 6 x 4
## Groups:   grp [2]
#  supp_date  tablet   grp adj_fill_dt
#  <date>      <int> <int> <date>
#1 2017-07-19     30     1 2017-07-19
#2 2017-08-07     30     1 2017-08-18
#3 2017-09-08     30     1 2017-09-17
#4 2017-10-30     30     2 2017-10-30
#5 2017-11-08     30     2 2017-11-29
#6 2017-12-07     30     2 2017-12-29
```

Comment: I didn't know `dplyr` had a built-in `if_else()` function. Thank you for introducing me that and to `lag()`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it now. I just changed row 4 to `2017-10-30`

Comment: @CristianE.Nuno I think in general `if_else` is preferred over base R's `ifelse`; amongst other things, `if_else` is faster than `ifelse`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse) is an interesting SO posts on the subject.

Comment: @MauritsEvers After the row 4 date was changed to `2017-10-30`, the codes are not working. It keeps the same loop forward, without breaking at `else`. I should provide `else` case in the first place. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Fred Hmm. Perhaps I misunderstood; but with the new data I don't see how we make it into the `else` part. Can you perhaps fix your sample code above and make it reproducible? When I try to run your `for` loop I get an error.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I don't have error message in the output. I have added your sample data, and one additional code to convert date to the question.

Comment: @Fred I've updated my answer with a solution that reproduces your output for both the earlier and revised sample data. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this recursively with `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = as.numeric(supp_date),
        adj_fill_dt = as.Date(accumulate(tmp[-1], ~
             pmax(.x + tablet[1], .y), .init = tmp[1]), 
                           origin = '1970-01-01'),
        tmp = NULL)
#   supp_date tablet adj_fill_dt
#1 2017-07-19     30  2017-07-19
#2 2017-08-07     30  2017-08-18
#3 2017-09-08     30  2017-09-17
#4 2017-10-30     30  2017-10-30
#5 2017-11-08     30  2017-11-29
#6 2017-12-07     30  2017-12-29
```

---

Or with `base R` using `Reduce`

```
v1 <- as.numeric(df$supp_date)
as.Date(Reduce(function(u, v)  pmax(u + 30, v), v1[-1], 
      init = v1[1], accumulate = TRUE), origin = '1970-01-01')
#[1] "2017-07-19" "2017-08-18" "2017-09-17" "2017-10-30" "2017-11-29"
#[6] "2017-12-29"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(supp_date = structure(c(17366, 17385, 17417, 17469, 
17478, 17507), class = "Date"), tablet = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L)), .Names = c("supp_date", "tablet"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you mind explaining the rational behind this?

Comment: @Fred In the `for` loop you are assigning new value at each step.  Logic is the same here with `accumulate`