# Ordering problems when using mutate with ifelse condition to date

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to use mutate to create a column that takes the value of one column up to a point and then uses `cumprod` to fill the rest of the observations based on the values of another column.

I tried combining `mutate` with `ifelse` but the order of the statements is not correct and I can't figure out why

Below I reproduce a more basic example that replicates my problem:

```
foo1 <- data.frame(date=seq(2005,2018,1))
foo1 %>% mutate(h=ifelse(date>2008, seq(1,11,1), 99))
```

The output is:

```
   date  h
1  2005 99
2  2006 99
3  2007 99
4  2008 99
5  2009  5
6  2010  6
7  2011  7
8  2012  8
9  2013  9
10 2014 10
11 2015  1
12 2016  2
13 2017  3
14 2018  4
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
   date  h
1  2005 99
2  2006 99
3  2007 99
4  2008 99
5  2009  1
6  2010  2
7  2011  3
8  2012  4
9  2013  5
10 2014  6
11 2015  7
12 2016  8
13 2017  9
14 2018 10
```

Edit:

Below I reproduce another example (more close to what I'm trying to do).

```
foo2 <- data.frame(date=seq(2005,2013,1), a=seq(1, by=1, length.out = 9), b=rep(1.01, length.out = 9))
foo2 %>% mutate(h=ifelse(date>2008, cumprod(c(a[5],b[5:9])), a))
```

The output I have is:

```
  date a    b       h
1 2005 1 1.01 1.00000
2 2006 2 1.01 2.00000
3 2007 3 1.01 3.00000
4 2008 4 1.01 4.00000
5 2009 5 1.01 5.20302
6 2010 6 1.01 5.25505
7 2011 7 1.01 5.00000
8 2012 8 1.01 5.05000
9 2013 9 1.01 5.10050
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
  date a    b       h
1 2005 1 1.01 1.00000
2 2006 2 1.01 2.00000
3 2007 3 1.01 3.00000
4 2008 4 1.01 4.00000
5 2009 5 1.01 5.00000
6 2010 6 1.01 5.05000
7 2011 7 1.01 5.10050
8 2012 8 1.01 5.20302
9 2013 9 1.01 5.25505
```

If I use if_else instead of `ifelse`, I receive the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `true` must be length 9 (length of `condition`) or one, not 6
```

Comment: Base R option : `foo1$h <- 99;
foo1$h[foo1$date > 2008] = 1:10`

Comment: Your edit is quite a different issue, but relates back to you not quite understanding how `ifelse` (or `if_else`) works. The error that `if_else` gives should give you an idea of where you are going wrong (which is exactly one of the reasons why you should use `dplyr::if_else` instead of base R `ifelse`).

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there:

```
foo1 %>% mutate(h = if_else(date > 2008, cumsum(date > 2008), 99L))
#   date  h
#1  2005 99
#2  2006 99
#3  2007 99
#4  2008 99
#5  2009  1
#6  2010  2
#7  2011  3
#8  2012  4
#9  2013  5
#10 2014  6
#11 2015  7
#12 2016  8
#13 2017  9
#14 2018 10
```

PS. It's recommended to use [`if_else` instead of base R's `ifelse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse).

Answer (score 2):

The `ifelse` function takes three arguments:

1. `test`: a `logical` vector. Say that it has a length of `N`.
2. `yes`: a vector. It can be of any length. If the length is not `N`, the vector is recycled/shortened to be of length `N`
3. `no`: same as `yes`.

At the end of this preprocessing stage, you have 3 same length vectors. `ifelse` then builds the return value selecting the second vector or the third vector depending on `test`.

In your case we have:

```
test <- foo1$date>2008 #length: 14
yes <- seq(1,11,1) #length: 11
no <- 99 #length: 1
```

So, it needs to recycle both `yes` and `no`. You end up with something like:

```
 test yes no
FALSE   1 99
FALSE   2 99
FALSE   3 99
FALSE   4 99
 TRUE   5 99
 TRUE   6 99
 TRUE   7 99
 TRUE   8 99
 TRUE   9 99
 TRUE  10 99
 TRUE  11 99
 TRUE   1 99
 TRUE   2 99
 TRUE   3 99
```

You see how the recycle works. Then, to build the return value, `ifelse` selects, in the order above, `yes` elements if `test` is `TRUE` and `no` elements otherwise. This explain why you have that return value. It's not about `dplyr` of course.