# ifelse over each element of a vector

Tags: r, if-statement

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042413/11117265), I thought `ifelse` is vectorized in the sense that `f(c(x1, x2, x3)) = c(f(x1), f(x2), f(x3))`.

So, I thought if the code for `z1` (provided below) will perform the following for each element of the vector `y`:

- Test whether it is unity or not.

  - If **YES**, draw a random number from {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}.
  - If **NO**, draw a random number from {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}.

But, unfortunately it doesn't do that. It generates once for each case, and returns that very random number always.

Where exactly am I doing wrong? Or, is it actually the expected behaviour of `ifelse`?

Just to note, if I use this as a wrapper function inside `sapply`, I get the expected output `z2` (in the sense that it is not deterministic as `z1` where observing one occurrence of each case is enough), as you can see below.

```r
y <- rbinom(n = 20,
            size = 1,
            prob = 0.5)

z1 <- ifelse(test = (y == 1),
             yes = sample(x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
                          size = 1),
             no = sample(x = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8),
                         size = 1))

z2 <- sapply(X = y,
             FUN = function(w)
             {
               ifelse(test = (w == 1),
                      yes = sample(x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
                                   size = 1),
                      no = sample(x = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8),
                                  size = 1))
             })

data.frame(y, z1, z2)
#>    y z1 z2
#> 1  0  2  2
#> 2  1  1  3
#> 3  1  1  9
#> 4  1  1  7
#> 5  0  2  0
#> 6  0  2  2
#> 7  1  1  7
#> 8  1  1  7
#> 9  0  2  0
#> 10 1  1  5
#> 11 0  2  0
#> 12 0  2  0
#> 13 0  2  6
#> 14 0  2  0
#> 15 0  2  2
#> 16 1  1  7
#> 17 1  1  7
#> 18 0  2  2
#> 19 0  2  2
#> 20 0  2  0

unique(x = z1[y == 1])
#> [1] 1

unique(x = z1[y == 0])
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ifelse` isn't a function of one vector, it is a function of *3 vectors of the same length*. The first vector, called `test`, is a boolean, the second vector `yes` and third vector `no` give the elements in the result, chosen item-by-item based on the `test` value.

A sample of `size = 1` is a different size than `test` (unless the length of `test` is 1), so it will be recycled  by `ifelse` (see note below). Instead, draw samples of the same size as `test` from the start:

```
ifelse(
   test = (y == 1),
   yes = sample(x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), size = length(y), replace = TRUE),
   no = sample(x = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8), size = lenght(y), replace = TRUE)
)
```

The vectors don't actually have to be of the same length. The help page `?ifelse` explains: *"If `yes` or `no` are too short, their elements are recycled.*" This is the behavior you observed with *"It generates once for each case, and returns that very random number always.*".

Comment: Just as a side note: I wouldn't say that "A sample of size = 1 is a different size than test, so it won't work with ifelse", because it's pretty common to have `yes` or `no` of size one. What should be outlined is that the value gets recycled, and that's why the OP obtained the same value for each group.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I've a question based on that. When you said that `ifelse` is a function of 3 vectors `test`, `yes` and `no`, do you mean that irrespective of the elements (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) of `test`, the other two (`yes` and `no`) gets calculated always, and the final result is then obtained by combining these two subject to the elements of `test`?

Comment: Yes, with the exception of if `test` is *always* TRUE or *always* false. See the help page `?ifelse`: *"`yes` will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is `true`, and analogously for `no`."* For way more detail (and checks), see [Does ifelse really calculate both of its vectors every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/903061)

Comment: Just to promote myself a bit, I answered a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520036/ordering-problems-when-using-mutate-with-ifelse-condition-to-date/53520746#53520746) without getting much (any to be fair) attention and explaining how the `ifelse` function works.

Comment: Thanks both of you, Gregor and @nicola for providing explanation and providing related references.