# Sample function repeats same value within ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, sample

I have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(Store = c("vpm", "vpm", 
"vpm"), Date = structure(c(18042, 18042, 18042), class = "Date"), 
    UniqueImageId = c("vp3_523", "vp3_668", "vp3_523"), EntryTime = structure(c(1558835514, 
    1558834942, 1558835523), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    ExitTime = structure(c(1558838793, 1558838793, 1558839824
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Duration = c(3279, 3851, 
    4301), Age = c(35L, 35L, 35L), EntryPoint = c("Entry2Side", 
    "Entry2Side", "Entry2Side"), ExitPoint = c("Exit2Side", "Exit2Side", 
    "Exit2Side"), AgeNew = c("15_20", "25_32", "15_20"), GenderNew = c("Female", 
    "Male", "Female")), row.names = 4:6, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I am trying to populate a random number for the column `AgeNew` and I am using `sample` function with ifelse condition.

I tried the following

```
d$AgeNew <- ifelse(d$AgeNew == "0_2",   sample(0:2,  1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "15_20", sample(15:20,1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "25_32", sample(25:36,1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "38_43", sample(36:43,1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "4_6",   sample(4:6,  1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "48_53", sample(48:53,1,replace = TRUE), 
            ifelse(d$AgeNew == "60_Inf",sample(60:65,1,replace = TRUE), 
                                        sample(8:13, 1,replace = TRUE))))))))
```

But I am getting the same value getting repeated.  For example, for the age group 0_2 I have only 2 populated.  I tried using `set.seed`

```
set.seed(123)
```

and then running the ifelse still it repeats the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed somewhere (cannot find the source at the moment). The reason it behaves like this is because `ifelse` runs only once for one condition hence, the value is recycled. Consider this example,

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, 1), sample(20:30, 1))
#[1]  1 26  1 26  1 26
ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, 1), sample(20:30, 1))
#[1] 10 28 10 28 10 28
ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, 1), sample(20:30, 1))
#[1]  9 24  9 24  9 24
```

As we can see it gives the same number which is recycled for both the scenarios. To avoid that we need to specify `size` of `sample` as length of the `test` condition in `ifelse`

```
ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, length(x)), sample(20:30, length(x)))
#[1]  7 23  1 26 10 24
ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, length(x)), sample(20:30, length(x)))
#[1]  3 23  5 26  6 22 
ifelse(x == 1, sample(1:10, length(x)), sample(20:30, length(x)))
#[1]  2 30  9 27  1 29
```

Comment: May be this answer by Gregor? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148487/11117265

Answer (score 1):

An easier option would be to replace the `_` with `:`, and `eval`uate and `sample` the elements within that range

```
library(data.table)
d[, AgeNew := sapply(sub("_", ":", sub('Inf', '65', AgeNew)),
           function(x) sample(eval(parse(text = x)), 1))]
d[is.na(AgeNew), AgeNew := sample(8:13, 1)]
d
#  Store       Date UniqueImageId           EntryTime            ExitTime Duration Age EntryPoint ExitPoint AgeNew GenderNew
#1:   vpm 2019-05-26       vp3_523 2019-05-25 21:51:54 2019-05-25 22:46:33     3279  35 Entry2Side Exit2Side     15    Female
#2:   vpm 2019-05-26       vp3_668 2019-05-25 21:42:22 2019-05-25 22:46:33     3851  35 Entry2Side Exit2Side     30      Male
#3:   vpm 2019-05-26       vp3_523 2019-05-25 21:52:03 2019-05-25 23:03:44     4301  35 Entry2Side Exit2Side     17    Female
```

---

Or another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
   mutate(AgeNew = str_replace(AgeNew, "Inf", "65")) %>%
   separate(AgeNew, into = c('start', 'end'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(AgNew = map2_int(start, end, ~ sample(.x:.y, 1)))
```

---

Or another option is to split by `_`, and then sample

```
d[, AgeNew := unlist(lapply(strsplit(sub('Inf', '65', AgeNew),  "_"), function(x)
            sample(as.numeric(x[1]):as.numeric(x[2]), 1)))]
```

---

Note that we don't need any nested `ifelse` to change here.  It is much easier to do this without any `ifelse`

NOTE2: The OP showed a `data.table` as example and here we are showing `data.table` methods

NOTE3: It is very inefficient to use nested ifelse

NOTE4: the `strsplit` based approach was first posted here

---

Regarding why `ifelse` works differently, it is already mentioned in the documentation of `?ifelse`

> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

Comment: getting this error    ` Error in `:=`(AgeNew, sapply(sub("_", ":", AgeNew), function(x) sample(eval(parse(text = x)),  : 
  could not find function ":=" `

Comment: @Apricot  Your dataset seems to be `data.table`.  So, I assume that you loaded `data.table`

Comment: whether I convert the file to a data frame or retain it as dataframe datatable...I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Apricot I don't get the error with the example you showed

Comment: @Apricot Is this error based on the example you showed or different data as I can't reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the `Inf`. From your example, I assume that you want to add `+5` if `Inf` appears. So based on that assumption, we can do,

```
sapply(strsplit(d$AgeNew, '_'), function(i){
                  sample(i[1]:replace(i[2], i[2] == 'Inf', as.numeric(i[1]) + 5), 1)
                  })

#[1] 60 32 19
```

**NOTE:** I changed the first entry of `AgeNew` to `60_Inf` in order to test