# How to collapse factors into "other" (not based on size)

Tags: r, forcats

I'm working with NHL player data and I basically want to compare a select Players points to the rest of the population. So I have the player data which looks like this:

```
 Player Season Team  Position    GP   TOI     G     A     P    P1 `P/60`
 <chr>   <int> <chr> <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 Aaron~   2019 FLA   D           35 603.      3     2     5     3   0.5 
 Adam ~   2019 CBJ   D            4  35.5     0     0     0     0   0  
Adam ~   2019 T.B   L           23 218.      2     7     9     5   2.48
```

and so on for the rest of the league. I'd like to compare a summary statistic between one of the observations to the rest of the data set.

```
 Player Season Team  Position    Summary Statistic
 <chr>   <int> <chr> <chr>             <int>
 Kasperi   2019 FLA   D                  45 
 "Others"  2019 CBJ   D                  53
```

I've seen fct_lump used to select the top records, sorted on some count - but when I tried something similar to using the Player names I couldn't get it to work.

```
NHL %>% 
 mutate(Player = fct_lump(Player,
                              Kasperi Kapanen = "Kasperi Kapanen",
                              other = !("Kasperi Kapanen")))
```

Comment: You can use `forcats::fct_other` and specify which level to keep. Everything else becomes the name you give as "other"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fct_lump` is not appropriate to handle the flexibility you want. you should use *dplyr's* `if_else` for one against all other observations

```
library(dplyr)
NHL %>% 
    mutate(Player = if_else(Player == "Kasperi Kapanen", "Kasperi Kapanen",
                                                         "others"))
```

**OR** `case_when` for multiple *ifelse* comparisons.

```
NHL %>% 
    mutate(Player = case_when(
                       Player == "Kasperi Kapanen" ~ "Kasperi Kapanen", 
                       Player == "Adam" ~ "Adam",
                       TRUE ~ "others" 
                             ))
```

Comment: [+1; in general it's better to use `dplyr`s `if_else` instead of base R's `ifelse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse).