# How to integrat mutate command with if/if else command?

Tags: r

I have the results of 260 different genotypes (4 different blocks of first repetition).  I used augmented block design. I want add a new column which express the genotype is check or not.   I know I have to use the combination of if/if else statement and mutate command. The problem is that I cannot integrate mutate command with if command?  Can anyone guide me how to integrate mutate command with if statement

Comment: To use `if/else`, it should return a single TRUE/FALSE. For e.g. `df1 %>% mutate(colNew = if(any(col1 > 5)) "Some Value" else "Other Value"`

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the ifelse statement,

it follows the same logic as if and else statements but has a yes, no and test scenario:

e.g.

mutate(dataframe, newcolumn = ifelse(test = what your testing, yes = what happens when test is true, no = what happens when test is false))

try that and post a reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `if_else` from the `dplyr` package instead of `ifelse` from base R, e.g.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(new_col = if_else(cond, col1, col2))
```

The advantage of `if_else` is that it is more strict and enables the user to set the NA value if a condition is not fullfilled. Compare: [dplyr if_else() vs base R ifelse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse)

Comment: But i just wanted to have one column which contains "Checks"( for the ones who have the criteria) and "Accession"( for the ones who have not the criteria)