# Conditional assignment of values in R: Comparison of methods and best practice

Tags: r, if-statement

Suppose I want to assign different values to `x` conditional on some other variables. If there are only two conditions, I could use `ifelse`. For more than two conditions, I would use if-else-statements. For example, suppose I wanted to make the following assignments:

- `x <- 1` if `y > 10 & y <= 20`
- `x <- 2` if `y > 20 & y <= 30`
- `x <- 3` if `y > 30 & y <= 50`

Normally, I would implement this in the following way (method 1):

```
if (y > 10 & y <= 20) {
  x <- 1
} else if (y > 20 & y <= 30) {
  x <- 2
} else if (y > 30 & y <= 50) {
  x <- 3
}
```

But I recently saw another way (method 2):

```
x <- if (y > 10 & y <= 20) {
  1
} else if (y > 20 & y <= 30) {
  2
} else if (y > 30 & y <= 50) {
  3
}
```

**Questions:**

- Are there any differences between method 1 and method 2 except
  personal preferences that I should be aware of (e.g. performance)?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of both methods, if any?
- Are there other methods you would recommend?

Comment: Look into `?ifelse`.

Comment: Look into `case_when` too https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654058/786542