# Unexpected behavior with dplyr and dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some dates:

```
dates.df <- seq(from=as.Date("2019-01-01"), to=as.Date("2019-01-07"), by = "day") %>% 
data.frame(date=.) 
dates.df

# date
# 2019-01-01
# 2019-01-02
# 2019-01-03
# 2019-01-04
# 2019-01-05
# 2019-01-06
# 2019-01-07
```

I would like to create a second column which mirrors the date in the first column unless the date is before 2019-01-04, in which case it should show 2019-01-04 like so:

```
# date          date.prime
# 2019-01-01    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-02    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-03    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-04    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-05    2019-01-05
# 2019-01-06    2019-01-06
# 2019-01-07    2019-01-07
```

I have tried:

```
dates.df %>% 
mutate(date.prime=ifelse(date < "2019-01-04", "2019-01-04", date))
```

But this yields:

```
# date          date.prime
# 2019-01-01    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-02    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-03    2019-01-04
# 2019-01-04    17900
# 2019-01-05    17901
# 2019-01-06    17902
# 2019-01-07    17903
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654058/786542

Comment: That worked, thank you! I wasn't even aware of if_else() until now.

Comment: You can also use `pmax(as.Date("2019-01-04"), date)` instead of the ifelse premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your attempt you are comparing `date` with character date (`"2019-01-04"`) and not actual date object which might give you unexpected results.

```
class("2019-01-04")
#[1] "character"
```

For comparison to work correctly, you need to convert it to date

```
class(as.Date("2019-01-04"))
#[1] "Date"
```

According to this if we change your attempt , we get

```
library(dplyr)

dates.df %>% 
   mutate(date.prime = ifelse(date < as.Date("2019-01-04"), 
                              as.Date("2019-01-04"), date))


#        date date.prime
#1 2019-01-01      17900
#2 2019-01-02      17900
#3 2019-01-03      17900
#4 2019-01-04      17900
#5 2019-01-05      17901
#6 2019-01-06      17902
#7 2019-01-07      17903
```

that is because `ifelse` makes date loose their class.

To overcome that, we can convert it to Date again.

```
dates.df %>% 
   mutate(date.prime = as.Date(ifelse(date < as.Date("2019-01-04"),
                       as.Date("2019-01-04"), date)))

#       date date.prime
#1 2019-01-01 2019-01-04
#2 2019-01-02 2019-01-04
#3 2019-01-03 2019-01-04
#4 2019-01-04 2019-01-04
#5 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
#6 2019-01-06 2019-01-06
#7 2019-01-07 2019-01-07
```

Or use the suggestions in the comments, use `if_else` as mentioned by @Tung

```
dates.df %>% 
  mutate(date.prime = if_else(date < as.Date("2019-01-04"), 
                      as.Date("2019-01-04"), date))
```

Or `pmax` as suggested by @r2evans

```
dates.df %>% 
   mutate(date.prime = pmax(as.Date("2019-01-04"), date))
```