# Translating a long Excel formula into Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably a very untraditional question, but I'm totally stumped. I just took over a project at work from a former co-worker who has been doing all of his reporting in Excel. It has lead to a ton of headaches with broken workbooks and what not. I've been able to translate almost all of his formula into some dplyr compatible. Except for this one problem:

```
=if (C3="Yes" ,if (B20>0, floor(B20/C4) + if (G3 <= mod(B20,C14), 1, ),),)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I know it would involve `case_when` but I'm stumped after that!

Comment: Please show some minimal sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have no idea, if we're being honest

Comment: More information is needed to provide a solid answer. For example, what cell is this formula in? What are B20, C3, C14, and G3? Are any of these constants? What columns exist in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, I've used the name of the Excel columns for the sake of simplicity.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  C3 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), 
  B20= c(10, 5, 0, 1), 
  G3 = c(1, 1, 20, 1),
  C4 = c(2, 5, 1, 1),  
  C14 = c(3, 5, 1, 1)
)
```

What you need to do is to call `if_else()` twice. For what follows, I
assume that the default value is 0 (note that you can use `NA` instead). 
Basically, if there were only the first statement, you would do:

```
df %>% mutate(EX = ifelse(C3 == "Yes", 1, 0))
   C3 B20 G3 C4 C14 EX
1 Yes  10  1  2   3  1
2 Yes   5  1  5   5  1
3 Yes   0 20  1   1  1
4  No   1  1  1   1  0
```

But there is a second part, and you need to call `if_else()` one more time:

```
df %>% mutate(EX = if_else(
  C3 == "Yes", 
  if_else(B20>0, floor(B20/C4) + (G3<=(B20%%C14)), 0),
  0))
   C3 B20 G3 C4 C14 EX
1 Yes  10  1  2   3  6
2 Yes   5  1  5   5  1
3 Yes   0 20  1   1  0
4  No   1  1  1   1  0
```

`%%` is the equivalent of `mod` in excel.

Comment: [Better to use `if_else` instead of `ifelse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse)

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you need to load `magrittr` as `dplyr` imports `magrittr` pipes.

Comment: @rdornas you are right! And Maurrits Evers, also agree with your comment and I edited my answer accordingly.