# How to write case-when-then

Tags: r

I have a table, for example:

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Y |  |
| 2 | B |  | Y |
| 3 | B |  | N |
| 4 | A | Y |  |

If I have an SQL query where I write:

```
Select 
Case when Field1 = '1' and Field2 = 'A' then Field3
Else Field4 End as NameOfField
From Table
```

Expected output is
|Field1|NameOfField|
|:-----|:----------|
|1     |   Y       |
|2     |   Y       |
|3     |   N       |
|4     |   Y       |

How can I write the same query in RStudio?

Comment: would this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/1.0.10/topics/case_when help?

Comment: I want to substitute end result with a field name and not with number or text value but, it is creating a problem at my end. Do u know about a query which can substitute not the value but field name? Thanks

Comment: Could you give us an example of your desired output?

Comment: I thought it is allowed to return a fieldname from the same data frame, or any expression involving those but with the same type and length as all branches.

Comment: Hi - I tried ifelse and case_when method but i am getting the error                        
  "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Hi @nightstand . I tried ifelse and case_when method but i am getting the error "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function". Could you please suggest?

Comment: Hi @tinazmu. ried ifelse and case_when method but i am getting the error "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function". Could you please suggest?

Comment: Sure, could you share with us your attempted code?

Answer (score 3):

As @tinazmu suggested, you can use the function `case_when` from `dplyr` package. An equivalent of your SQL query in R would be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(
    NameOfField = case_when(Field1 == "1" & Field2 == "A" ~ Field3,
                            TRUE ~ Field4)
  )
```

With an output:

```
#>   Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 NameOfField
#> 1      1      A      Y   <NA>           Y
#> 2      2      B   <NA>      Y           Y
#> 3      3      B   <NA>      N           N
#> 4      4      A      Y   <NA>        <NA>
```

In addition, since your query only checks for one condition, I can suggest another way using `ifelse`:

```
df |>
  mutate(
    NameOfField = ifelse(Field1 == "1" & Field2 == "A",
                         Field3,
                         Field4)
  )

# output
#>   Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 NameOfField
#> 1      1      A      Y   <NA>           Y
#> 2      2      B   <NA>      Y           Y
#> 3      3      B   <NA>      N           N
#> 4      4      A      Y   <NA>        <NA>
```

---

**Data**:

```
df <- read.table(text="Field1   Field2  Field3  Field4
1   A   Y   NA
2   B   NA  Y
3   B   NA  N
4   A   Y   NA", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")
```

Comment: Since you are already using `dplyr`, you might as well use `dplyr::if_else()`, which has some advantages [e.g., see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646133/dplyr-if-else-vs-base-r-ifelse).